# Meaning of なし得ないことをなし得えられない

Tags: meaning, parsing

> だからね、このプロレスの世界で一番大事なのって何だかわかります？
>   ――なんですか？
>   フフフ。それは“タイミング”なんですよ。その場所、その時間にいなきゃ、なし得ないことをなし得えられない。それがタイミングじゃないですか。ジェリコはいままでプロレスラーとしての栄光。その“全部”をなし得てるんですよ。

In this interview that I'm reading there's a part where the interviewee is trying to define the concept of "timing" in the context of two people doing a special sports performance (ala Mayweather vs McGregor) but I can't understand the structure of the sentence

> その場所、その時間にいなきゃ、なし得ないことをなし得えられない。それがタイミングじゃないですか。

Is なし a negative prefix in here or is this some kind of idiom?, also, is 得えられない correctly typed or should it be 得られない?

The translation I have for that sentence is:

> It’s timing. Just the combination of absolute best time and absolute best place to do something nobody would think possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This なす before 得 is [為す or 成す](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%82%BA%E3%81%99) in kanji, and means "to achieve/accomplish". 為し得る is "to be able to accomplish." 無し is not relevant.

なし得えられない is an obvious typo, but なし得られない still sounds weird to me (two potential forms in succession, "can be able to ...(?)"). Anyway it should mean the same thing as なし得ない.

The sentence is saying:

> 「その場所、その時間にいなきゃ、なし得ないこと」をなし得えられない。
>   You cannot achieve [what cannot be achieved unless you are at that place, at that time].

Or more simply, "(If your タイミング is bad,) You cannot achieve a thing that requires the right time and place. (That's what タイミング means.)"

As usual, please don't be deceived by the commas.